# Connect application written with Entity Framework to SQL Server 2014 database from client maschine

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

[image]

[image]

[image]

I developed a simple application that is based on the Entity Framework 6.

The same application uses a database that was created in SQL Server 2014. When I run the application from my computer everything is ok and working properly .

But now I want to try to run the same application with my other computers. Two computers are networked, belong to the same network group.

All protocols in SQL Server configuration are enabled. What is needed more to do that I can successfully launch the application?

My application is written with Visual Studio and vb.net as programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- possibly you have localhost in the connection string in the config. file of your application
- sql server browser doesn't run on pc where sql server runs.
- sql ports are not allowed in your firewall

Comment: ok, I'll try. Hm, in Sql server 2008 I had to install the SQL client , but i can not find SQL client 2014

Comment: check outbound rules in firewall on your  sql server machine

Comment: it is turned off. When i go on control panel/ administration tool and as diffrent user I try to connect using first sql client 11, sql server and ODBC. I successfully access to the server and it is weird because i use the same connection string in my applications . Yet over the applications can not be pesters